# Tailwind css carousel example not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

In a `next.js` project, I am trying to build a carousel using this example :
https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/

I have installed `tailwindcss@2.0.2` do i need anything else to make CSS work.

Comment: can we see your react code? probably you made a mistake, but I can't realize what exactly happend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you need to install the tailwind element package

`npm install tw-elements`
and then require it in `tailwind.config.js`

take a look at the starter guide :
https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/

or you can just include the CDN scripts and stylesheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/css/index.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/js/index.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please, make sure this.

1. Before starting the project, install Node.js (LTS) and TailwindCSS.
2. Run the following command to install the package via NPM:

**TERMINAL**

```
 npm install tw-elements
```

3. Tailwind Elements is a plugin and should be included inside the tailwind.config.js file. It is also recommended to extend the content array with a js file that loads dynamic component classes:

**TAILWIND.CONFIG.JS**

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js}', './node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/**/*.js'],
  plugins: [
    require('tw-elements/dist/plugin')
  ]
}
```

4. Dynamic components will work after adding the js file:

**INDEX.HTML**

```
 <script src="./TW-ELEMENTS-PATH/dist/js/index.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can import it in the following way (bundler version):

**INDEX.JS**

```
  import 'tw-elements';
```